# I get an int error when trying to run a simple addition calculator i made in python

Tags: python

When trying to run this simple calculator with only addition and passing "1 + 2" in the terminal without quotes

```
numbers=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
str=input()
numlist = str.split()
for i in range(len(numlist)):
    number=""
    operate=""
    for j in numlist[i]:
        if j in numbers:
            number=number+j
        else:
            operate=operate+j
    if operate == "+":
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(numlist)):
            sum = sum + int(number)
```

it results In this

````
Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
  File "C:\Users\dummy\Desktop\New Text Document.py", line 15, in <module>
    sum = sum + int(number)
```'
Any help would be appreciated
````

Comment: Do you provide the input in  this format ? 1  2  3 . . . Numbers with spaces

Comment: Is there a new line at the end of the file?

Comment: Yes i provide spaces between the numbers and no there is no new line at the end

Comment: What does the `numlist` look like after you split the input?

Comment: try : `sum = sum + int(float(number))` I think you have passed an empty string in input.

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
could not convert string to float: ' '  that is what it does debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you iterate through numlist you are resetting `number` to an empty string. I'd suggest moving that and sum above your for loop to make sure they are not reset on each iteration.

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
given_input = input()
numlist = given_input.split()
number = ""
operate = ""
sum = 0
for i in numlist:
    for j in i:
        if j in numbers:
            number = j
        else:
            operate = j
    if operate == "+" and number != "":
        sum += int(number)
        number = ""
print(sum)
```

Comment: IT WORKS YOU LEGEND

Comment: I have one more question tho now that it works if you try multiple additions then like 45 + 23 + 11 it results in a number in the thousands can you help with that?

Comment: I've updated the comment to show my iteration on this... The problem is that you had the number saved for the previous iteration... Also adding the number + j, which was concatenating a string & int (resulting in something like 45 + 1 = 451). Which is why you were getting numbers over a thousand.